# Maui 6 WebView Timout handling

Tags: webview, maui

Im trying to handle webview timeout in my project.

If i want to check for network connectivity at startup , i can do this :

```cs
if(!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{
   //You are offline, notify the user
   return null;
}
```

but the problem is , i want to check exact website for connectivity.

and this should happen during navigation inside website.(may be some pages goes timeout and i should

show the message to person)this is my code :

```cs
string url = "xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx";
webview.Source = url;
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("Custom", (handler, view) =>
{
#if ANDROID
    handler.PlatformView.Settings.CacheMode = Android.Webkit.CacheModes.Default;
    handler.PlatformView.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
    handler.PlatformView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    handler.PlatformView.AddJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptHandler(), "Native");
#endif
});
```

Ive tried the Maui IsConnected method but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Could you elaborate more please.

Comment: WebView has Navigation method, have you tried check the connectivity in Navigating event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView has [Navigation and Navigated events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?pivots=devices-android#perform-navigation)

You may try using Navigated event for webview.

```
<WebView x:Name="mywebview" Navigated="mywebview_Navigated" .../>
```

And in code-behind event handler, you could implement your logic (such as display an alert) based on the result like this:

```
void mywebview_Navigated(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Result)
    {
        case WebNavigationResult.Cancel:
            // your logic
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Failure:
            // your logic
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Success:
            // your logic
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Timeout:
            // your logic
            break;
        default:
            // your logic
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!